# htaccess - Rewrite root folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've had a good look on Google but couldn't see any examples of my scenario... or none that I could understand lol.

Here's my situation.  I have a htaccess rewrite that takes the url http://www.mydomain.com/advert and points to http://www.mydomain.com/adverts/juneadvert/index.php
This works fine, however, I want all the source code paths (javascript, css etc) to use the /advert slug too.  That way the true path is hidden from the user.

E.g. I dont want:
http://www.mydomain.com/adverts/juneadvert/css/style.css

I do want:
http://www.mydomain.com/advert/css/style.css

Is this possible?

Comment: Apologies for that.  I've ticked working answers.  I'll try much harder from now on - I appreciate developers taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is just 1 line rule like this:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^advert/((css|js)/.*)$ /adverts/juneadvert/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @user287212 and @ Tomgrohl, You're most welcome. Appreciate that you found my answer useful.